# V3125 false positive when having empty statement after return

Tags: pvs-studio

This minimal example triggers V3125 about `member` being used after it was verified against null. If I remove the extra semicolon after the first return statement V3125 is no longer triggered.

```
public class PVS_nullcheck
{
    private object member;

    public int Method()
    {
        if (member == null)
        {
            return 0;
            ; // <-- 3125
        }

        return member.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback. We have fixed this false alarm, the fix will be available in the next release version of PVS-Studio. You can download the latest beta from [here](http://files.viva64.com/beta/PVS-Studio_setup.exe).